# PDF generated and merged upside down with pdfforge

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I use a code to generate pdf and to merge with others pdfs. But the pdfs I merge are upside down. The original pdfs are right side up. All codes and functions are here in the order of process.

Code saving originals in a file and create one with all merged using pdfforge.

Edit : I reduce my code here, first I get the different pdfs, second I launch functions to merge its.

```
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ticket_FO_Documents", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ticket_FO_Justificatif_Delegation", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "[Ticket_FO_Pièces jointes]", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ticket_MO_Documents", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ticket_BO_Documents", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ordre_Justificatif_Validation", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
recuperer_PJ strChemin3, "Ticket", "Ticket_BO_Documents_Conformité", "(((Ticket.[Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket])='" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & "'))"
'Fusion des PJ
PilotageMacro1 strChemin3, strChemin2 & "\" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & " - " & Me!Titre & ".pdf"

FileMove strChemin2 & "\" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & " - " & Me!Titre & ".pdf", strChemin3 & "\" & Me![Ticket_FO_Numéro ticket] & " - " & Me!Titre & " initial complet.pdf"
```

function to save and launch the "mergage"

```
Public Sub recuperer_PJ(ByVal strNomDestination As String, ByVal strTable As String, ByVal strChamp As String, ByVal strWhere As String)
  Dim rst1 As DAO.Recordset
  Dim rst2 As DAO.Recordset
  Dim strSQL As String

  ' Se positionner sur l'enregistrement souhaité
  strSQL = "SELECT * FROM " & strTable & " WHERE" & strWhere & ";"
  Set rst1 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot)

  ' Obtenir le "sous-recordset" des pièces jointes
  Set rst2 = rst1(strChamp).Value

  ' Lister les pièces jointes
  While Not rst2.EOF
  test = 0
  dossier = strNomDestination & "\"
  Do While Not test = 1
  txt = Dir(dossier & rst2.Fields("FileName"))
  If txt = "" Then
  test = 1
  Else
  dossier = dossier & "_"
  End If
  Loop
  dossier = dossier & rst2.Fields("FileName")
  rst2.Fields(0).SaveToFile dossier
  rst2.MoveNext
  Wend

  ' On ferme les 2 Recordsets
  rst2.Close
  Set rst2 = Nothing
  rst1.Close
  Set rst1 = Nothing
End Sub
```

functions to merge

```
Public Sub PilotageMacro1(ByVal dossierFusion As String, ByVal dossierSortie As String)
    Dim Xl As Excel.Application
    Dim wbk As Excel.Workbook

    ' Démarrer Excel et le rendre visible
    Set Xl = New Excel.Application
    Xl.Visible = False


    ' Ouvrir le classeur qui contient les macros
Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Lien PDF] FROM Paramêtres")
Lien_PDF = rs.Fields(0)
Set wbk = Xl.Workbooks.Open(Lien_PDF & ".xlsm")
    'Set wbk = xl.Workbooks.Open(Lien_Dossier_Tickets & "\A_ne_pas_supprimer_G2T.xlsm")

    ' Exécuter une macro
    Xl.Run "SelDossierFusion", dossierFusion, dossierSortie

    ' Fermer le classeur sans l'enregistrer
    wbk.Close False
    Set wbk = Nothing

    ' Quitter Excel
    Xl.Quit
    Set Xl = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
Option Explicit

Dim Cpt As Long
Dim Tableau() As Variant
Const TypeFichier As String = "*.pdf"

Private Sub Fusion(ByVal dossierSortie As String)
Dim Pdf As Object
    Set Pdf = CreateObject("pdfforge.pdf.pdf")
    Pdf.MergePDFFiles_2 Tableau, dossierSortie, True
    Set Pdf = Nothing
End Sub

Private Sub ListeFichiers(ByVal sChemin As String, ByVal Recursif As Boolean)
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Dossier As Object
Dim SousDossier As Object
Dim Fichier As Object

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Dossier = FSO.GetFolder(sChemin)

    For Each Fichier In Dossier.Files
        If UCase(Fichier.Name) Like UCase(TypeFichier) Then
            ReDim Preserve Tableau(Cpt)
            Tableau(Cpt) = Fichier.Path
            Cpt = Cpt + 1
            Application.StatusBar = Cpt
        End If
    Next Fichier

    If Recursif Then
        For Each SousDossier In Dossier.SubFolders
            ListeFichiers SousDossier.Path, True
        Next SousDossier
    End If

    Set Dossier = Nothing
    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub

Sub SelDossierFusion(ByVal dossierFusion As String, ByVal dossierSortie As String)
Dim sChemin As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Dossier As Object
sChemin = dossierFusion

    Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set Dossier = FSO.GetFolder(sChemin)

           '    ListeFichiers récursive ou non True/False
            ListeFichiers Dossier, True
            Fusion (dossierSortie)

    Set FSO = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The issue is right in the middle of the **huge code dump** you provided. Sorry for my tone, but if you read about creating a [mcve] you will get *much more help* in solving your issue. No one is going to want to go through this amount of code to fish out an issue for you. It would also be wise to point out you are using `pdfforge`

Comment: *"but if you read about creating a minimal reproducible example you will get much more help in solving your issue"* - Actually merely reading about it won't suffice, you'll have to *do* it ;). Nonetheless, @Scott is right of course, providing a wall of code is about as bad as providing no code at all.

Comment: @mkl - well said :)

Comment: @mkl I modified